# Xtext - providing scope with a list of string literals

Tags: xtext

In scope provider class, I want to return an instance of 'Elist'. However 'scopedFor' is not accepting it as 'String' does not extend 'EObject'. I think I am missing something fundamental. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet that illustrates what you tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

scopes are for cross references. you cannot cross reference to a string. so could you elaborate what you really want to do?